# How to add a ngb tooltip in bootsrap range

Tags: angular, typescript, range, tooltip, bootstrap-5

I want to have a custom tooltip, When it slide the value of tooltip is also change and also Is it possible the tooltip will be always above the thumb when sliding?

```
<input type="range" class="form-range" min="0" max="15" id="form-range"
   [(ngModel)]="rangeValue" (input)="updateTooltip()" 
   [ngbTooltip]="currentTooltip" placement="top">
```

where:

```
tooltips: string[] = ['Snow White', 'Little Mermaid', 'Cinderella', 
                      'Aurora', 'Belle','Jasmine', 'Pocahontas',
                      'Mulan', 'Tiana', 'Rapunzel','Merida', 
                      'Elsa', 'Anna', 'Moana', 'Raya'];
rangeValue: number = 0;
currentTooltip: string = this.tooltips[0];

updateTooltip(): void {
   this.currentTooltip = this.tooltips[this.rangeValue];
}
```